# How does Java draw text under Windows operating system?

Tags: java

My question relates to the underlying rendering mechanism.  Does it use Windows APIs e.g. drawtext, exttextout or does it use a proprietary drawing mechanism?  Is this documented anywhere?

More specifically

```
java.awt.Graphics.drawString
java.awt.Graphics2D.drawString
```

Under Sun JDK for windows

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Which library?  Otherwise the default answer will be "It uses the JVM."

Comment: I believe he's asking "how does the JVM render text", which of course depends on exactly what JVM you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I've researched this when developping a PDF library.

Java, more specifically an implementation of Java, since it's not part of the public java-API, has libraries for parsing font-files and returning so-called "glyphs". These glyphs are then rendered using Graphics.

(Edit: glyphs are vectorgraphical (i.e. `java.awt.Shape`s) components that make readible symbols (Latin charset for instance, but also Hebrew or Arabic).)

To answer your question: it does not use Windows APIs such as drawtext. It may use Windows APIs to get font glyphs (depends on implementation of Java). As far as I know, Sun Java have closed-source font libraries which give you the glyphs.

You can, though, use glyphs provided by the libraries of any implementation of Java:

```
createGlyphVector(FontRenderContext frc, String str)
```

in `java.awt.Font`.

That should be a nice jumpstart. If you'd need anything: the rest is quite nicely documentated in the JavaDocs, i.e. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html

Answer (score 1):

For desktop applications, the [Swing windowing API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) does all the work, including drawing text to the screen. The only thing Swing relies on from the operating system is a window context, and a canvas to draw on. All widgets within the window are handled entirely within Swing.

AWT, by comparison, uses operating system constructs to do its rendering.

Comment: He's asking specifically about Graphics.drawString, not drawing components or buttons. Graphics.drawString would be one of the functions that Swing uses to actually do it's drawing.

Comment: My bad. Edit came after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.  It's supposed to work the same way on every operating system, so it could be done using OpenGL or DirectDraw or some other technology on windows.  And of course on other operating systems it's going to work differently.

If you're *really* curious, you can download the [JDK source code](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/) see how the functions are actually implemented.

Comment: Actually, besides the very informative JDK source code, it's not the "complete" implementation of a JRE: in text processing some parts are propretairy (because of font-licencing), and thus not included in the JDK source.
Perhaps OpenJDK is a better learning resource.